# How can I get the corresponding user_id (auto increment) value of a particular row in my database?

Tags: php, mysql

My table has 2 columns, user_id and username. The user logs in with username like this :

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];

//need to keep this in a session, for other pages later on
session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if(isset($check)) :

//if the username exists in the database, then show a html submit button
$con->close();
?>
     <html>
<body>
<form action="UserDetails.php" method="post">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
     </html>

<?php  else :{
    //if user is not in db, show this message
         echo 'Sorry about that, you can't come in.';
     }
     $con->close();
 ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I get the user_id that corresponds to username, to be used in pages later on ?

Comment: You mean you want to access `user_id` on *UserDetails.php* page, right?

Comment: Get it from the resultset of your SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(isset($check))` seemed to be causing me trouble, sometimes returning `user_id`, sometimes not.

Thanks in large part to Nabeel's answer, this idea worked for me. And also thanks to Solrac Ragnarockradio for putting me on track to make my code more secure with mysqli_real_escape_string :

```
<?php
require('dbConnect.php');

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_id = $row["user_id"];

//give me the corresponding user_id of the logged in user
echo $user_id;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {
    echo "Failed, sorry";
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "User id exists already.";

    }

$con->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A few problems here:

1) If you are using `"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $1` then **username** column should be **UNIQUE** and never forget to escape your input:

```
<?php
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");
```

2) You could check if you have any results b4 anything and assign those vars straight from the db...

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
 $error = "This user doesn't exists here...";
}else{
  $user_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query);
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user_info['username'];
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_info['user_id'];

}

$con->close();
?>
```

Then you can output whatever you want for logged in users if `$_SESSION['user_id']` is actually there...

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="UserDetails.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

<?php
 echo 'Well, here\'s the output: <b>'. (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : $error).'</b>';
```

Comment: plus 1 for mysql_real_escape_string tip, I've done that now.

Comment: But use mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

After these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Add these lines:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_id = $row["user_id"];
```

Comment: If you want to use $user_id on other pages as well, use Sessions.

Comment: Thanks, but it is only working on duplicates in my database, 
not single entries. For example, `user_id=1, username=Bill;` give me nothing when I echo `$user_id` but if I have duplicates like `user_id=1, username=Bill; user_id=2, username =Bill`, when I echo
`$user_id` I get `1`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`isset($check)` isnt save at this point, better check for the value of $check and the `{}` after `else` arent needed and it will not work.